# Does Apache Griffin work with Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache, validation, apache-nifi

If I wanted to validate data from a Nifi job, can I use apache griffin?

https://griffin.incubator.apache.org

https://nifi.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Griffin uses a REST API, so you can use the [`InvokeHTTP`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) processor in NiFi to communicate with that service and receive a validation result.